# Adding help button to SWT GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a simple swt GUI in my Eclipse application, which looks like the following:

[image: Ecllipse appication window]

It is implemented very simply:

```
// creating the label
Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
label.setText("Label");
// creating the input field
Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
text.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

I would like to add an button between the label and the input element, so that the user can get additional help on what to add inide the field.

It can either be a help button or just a icon which shows information in mouse hover.

How do I implement that? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Note: It looks like you are trying to reuse a GridData object here - never do this, always create a new GridData for each control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the many ways to do this is to use an information field decoration.

Something like:

```
Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);

FieldDecorationRegistry decRegistry = FieldDecorationRegistry.getDefault();

FieldDecoration infoField = decRegistry.getFieldDecoration(FieldDecorationRegistry.DEC_INFORMATION);

ControlDecoration decoration = new ControlDecoration(text, SWT.TOP | SWT.LEFT);
decoration.setImage(infoField.getImage());

decoration.setDescriptionText("Info decoration text");

GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);

// Space for decoration image
gridData.horizontalIndent = decRegistry.getMaximumDecorationWidth();

text.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!